# Este enunciado, ¿está incorrecto?

Tags: gramática, concordancia-gramatical

> Si supieras que me habría gustado la pizza si solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso.

¿Ustedes creen que sea incorrecto o puede estar bien?
En este enunciado estoy usando doble condicional.

Answer (score 2):

Si, la frase no es correcta y aparece incomprensible tal cómo está;  escrita con dos enunciados anidados y el principal inconcluso. La oración refiere **[a]** la posibilidad  de que otro (tu) sepa(s) acerca de **[b]** el (mi) frustado gusto de una pizza con demasiado queso.

> a) Si supieras que
>
> > b) la pizza me habría gustado si [*tan*] solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso

> c) ... *<qué pasaría>* **[esto no está]**

Por lo que se ve, el problema es del enunciado condicional principal, que necesita cerrar su sentido *con la implicancia, o la consecuencia posible de ese hecho*. En todo caso, mínimamente le falta la insinuación sugestiva, abierta y múltiple que dan los puntos suspensivos (**"..."**)

Una re-escritura simple le daría legibilidad a la frase quitando la repetición condicional, por ejemplo, si acaso para significar un deseo, diciendo:

> ¡Ay!, ojalá supieras que la pizza me habría gustado de no haber tenido tanto queso

Answer (score 1):

La oración:

> Si supieras que me habría gustado la pizza si solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso.

sólo funcionaría, en mi opinión, como expresión de deseo y con puntos suspensivos, puesto que se está omitiendo la apódosis, es decir, la proposición principal que completa el sentido de la oración:

- Si supieras que me habría gustado la pizza si solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso...
- Si (tan solo) supieras que me habría gustado la pizza si solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso, me habrías comprado una con menos queso.

Cabe destacar que, dentro de la condición o prótasis de la oración principal, hay una proposición nominal que a su vez contiene otra oración condicional:

- Me habría gustado la pizza si solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso.

Esta oración está incluida dentro de la prótasis de la oración principal como una proposición nominal introducida por la conjunción "que":

- Si (tan solo) supieras **que** me habría gustado la pizza si solo no le hubieran puesto tanto queso... (Si (tan solo) supieras **eso**...)

Comment: Muchas gracias.